# Polymorphic relationship inside a join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create a "composable" article model, where a user might create an `Article` then add any number of different "blocks", for example: a `TextBlock`, a `VideoBlock` then lastly a `GalleryBlock`.

I want to be able to something like this:

```
a = Article.find(1)
text = TextBlock.new
text.content = "blah"
a.blocks << text

puts a.blocks
# =>[TextBlock, VideoBlock, ...]
```

`TextBlock`, `VideoBlock` and `GalleryBlock` are dissimilar enough that using STI is a bad fit.

I think it may be possible to do what I want by having a join table, where one of its relationships is polymorphic, but I haven't been able to get it to work.

Here is where roughly where I'm at, but it wont function:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :article_blocks
  has_many :blocks, through: :article_blocks
end

class TextBlock < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :article_block, as: :block
  has_one :article, through: :article_block
end

class ArticleBlock < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :article
  belongs_to :block, polymorphic: true
end
```

And my schema

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150520030333) do

  create_table "article_blocks", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "article_id"
    t.integer  "block_id"
    t.string   "block_type"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  add_index "article_blocks", ["article_id"], name: "index_article_blocks_on_article_id"
  add_index "article_blocks", ["block_type", "block_id"], name: "index_article_blocks_on_block_type_and_block_id"

  create_table "articles", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "text_blocks", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text     "content"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

end
```

If I try to access an articles blocks, I get this error:

```
irb> x = Article.new
=> #<Article id: nil, title: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
irb> x.blocks
ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughAssociationPolymorphicSourceError: Cannot have a has_many :through association 'Article#blocks' on the polymorphic object 'Block#block' without 'source_type'. Try adding 'source_type: "Block"' to 'has_many :through' definition.
```

If I add the `source_type: "Block"` I get a type error (because that class doesn't exist). If I change it to `source_type: "ArticleBlock"`, the code doesn't fail but I can't insert TextBlocks into it because text blocks are the wrong type.

```
x = Article.new
=> #<Article id: nil, title: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
irb> x.blocks
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
irb> t = TextBlock.new
=> #<TextBlock id: nil, content: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
irb> t.content = "This is my text content"
=> "This is my text content"
irb> x.blocks << t
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch: ArticleBlock(#70362257715180) expected, got TextBlock(#70362257254480)
```

Comment: yes you are going right . could you please let me know  what issue you are suffering with the above   ?

Answer (score 0):

Right now, there's no clear relationship between your join table and `Article`. Because it's looking for a `Section` object per your query, you can start by adjusting your `Article` class to act as a section with `has_many :article_blocks, as: :section`.

Secondly, because you have a `has_one` relationship on `TextBlock` in relation to `ArticleBlock`, make sure the syntax reads `has_one :article_block, as: :block`

Comment: Sorry I some how missed that during the proof reads. I was trying to minimise the problem and abstract it out the existing code.